# How to provide simple-to-apply patches for an SDK?

Tags: git, diff, vst

I maintain an Open Source C++ framework for developing audio plugins called [wdl-ol](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol). A new version that I'm working requires several changes to be applied to the Steinberg VST3 SDK, which is an SDK that is not available under a publicly accessible version control system. Developers must fill in a form on the Steinberg website and download a zip file containing the source code.

The changes that i need to make do not affect the core API of VST3... so plugins retain compatibility with VST3 hosts etc. The changes relate to wrapper code that converts VST3 plugins into Audiounit and VST2 plugin formats and also some modifications to the IDE projects so that they work with the build system used by my plugin framework.

I want other people using my framework to be able to quickly get set up, so I don't want them to have to manually apply changes.

***My question***: what would be a good way to provide patches that users can apply?

My ideal would be:

1. developer checks out WDL-OL via git
2. developer downloads .zip file from steinberg and extracts it to the WDL-OL/VST3SDK folder
3. developer runs shell script which applies patches to the relevant VST3 files

Thanks for any tips

Comment: if you have a git patch, providing a simple shell script with something similar to `git apply - << BATCH-EMBEDDED-PATCH-END(eol)actual patch text(eol)BATCH-EMBEDDED-PATCH-END(eol)` could do the trick?

Comment: thanks. I've got something like this working, but having lots of trouble making sure the patch applies on windows and on osx due to line endings

Comment: unfortunately I see no options to ignore the kind of line ending in the source side of the patches in `git apply` (some other patch application tool may have that, but will probably not be installed on user machine :( )